# Convert List of Equations To Coefficient Matrix

Tags: list-manipulation, matrix

I have the following list of 2 equations (but generally I have much more than 2 equations):

```
  m= {A1*x+B1*Sin[x]-C1*Cos[x],C2+A2*Cosh[x]}
```

How could I automatically convert it into a coefficient matrix, like that:

$$\left(
\begin{array}{cccccc}
 \text{A1} \text{x4} & \text{B1} \sin (\text{x4}) & \text{-C1} \cos (\text{x4}) & 0 & 0 & 0
   \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & \text{A2} \cosh (\text{x4}) & \text{0} & \text{C2} \\
\end{array}
\right)$$

Each row of the coefficient matrix corresponds to an element of the `m` list and is sorted from A to Z.

**Some more details:**

Basically I have two equations:

(1) A1*x+B1*Sin[x]-C1*Cos[x]

(2) C2+ A2*Cosh[x]

Those equations are listed in the `m` list. I could rewrite those equations like that:

(1) A1*x + B1*Sin[x] - C1*Cos[x] + 0*A2 + 0*B2+0*C2

(2) 0*A1 + 0*B1 + 0*C1+A2*Cosh[x] + 0*B2+C2

Now I create the coefficient matrix:

$$\left(
\begin{array}{cccccc}
 \text{A1} \text{x4} & \text{B1} \sin (\text{x4}) & \text{-C1} \cos (\text{x4}) & 0 & 0 & 0
   \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & \text{A2} \cosh (\text{x4}) & \text{0} & \text{C2} \\
\end{array}
\right)$$

Comment: I don't understand it.

Comment: @HenrikSchumacher Sorry, there was a mistake in my question. I fixed it and I am adding mor information.

Comment: @HenrikSchumacher Please have a look at my updated question.

Comment: But where are "equations"? `==0`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 vars = {A1, B1, C1, A2, B2, C2};
 vars # & /@ CoefficientArrays[m, vars][[2]] // MatrixForm // TeXForm
```

> $\left(
> \begin{array}{cccccc}
>  \text{A1} x & \text{B1} \sin (x) & -\text{C1} \cos (x) & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
>  0 & 0 & 0 & \text{A2} \cosh (x) & 0 & \text{C2} \\
> \end{array}
> \right)$

**Update:** to also automate *vars*:

```
ClearAll[f]
f[n_, m_] := Flatten@Transpose[Outer[Symbol@StringJoin[##] &, 
  CharacterRange["A", "Z"][[;; m]], ToString /@ Range[n]]]
```

Examples:

```
f[2, 3]
```

> {A1, B1, C1, A2, B2, C2}

```
f[4, 4]
```

> {A1, B1, C1, D1, A2, B2, C2, D2, A3, B3, C3, D3, A4, B4, C4, D4}

Comment: Thanks a lot ! This works nicely. One question: Would it be possible to also automate vars ? I have n equation and m variables. ... a function that would take in the variable names and add the numbers: f(A,B,C) results in {A1,B1,C1,A2,B2,C2}

Comment: @james, you can do  `vars = Flatten@Transpose[
  Outer[Symbol@StringJoin[##] &, CharacterRange["A", "Z"][[;;m]], 
   ToString /@ Range[n]]]`

Comment: Great ! Thanks a lot !

Comment: Just a question: How can I get the coef. matrix in list form ?

Comment: @james, just use `vars # & /@ CoefficientArrays[m, vars][[2]]` (i.e. remove `MatrixForm` and `TeXForm` wrappers.

Comment: Then I get somethig with sparse array ... Ideally, I would need something like that {{row1},{row2},{row4},,,}}

Comment: sorry,  use `Normal[vars # & /@ CoefficientArrays[m, vars][[2]]]`

Comment: Okay ! Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 2):

`CoefficientArrays` is quite suitable for this job.

```
m = {A1 x + B1 Sin[x] - C1 Cos[x], C2 + A2 Cosh[x]};
eqs = Thread[m + {a, b} == 0];
CoefficientArrays[eqs, {A1, B1, C1, A2, B2, C2}] // Normal
```

> ```
> {{a, b}, 
>  {{x, Sin[x], -Cos[x], 0, 0, 0},
>   {0, 0, 0, Cosh[x], 0, 1}}
> }
> ```

Comment: Thanks a lot !  One question: Would it be possible to also automate vars ? I have n equation and m variables. ... a function that would take in the variable names and add the numbers: f(A,B,C) results in {A1,B1,C1,A2,B2,C2}

Comment: @james Do you mean that $ m $ is a multiple of 3?

Comment: The question was already answered. Please see update of the accepted answer. Thanks ! :)